# WP8 (Windows Phone 8) HTML5 App resized when keyboard opens

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

I'm building an HTML5 app for Windows Phone 8 and I noticed whenever the keyboard opens the app window is resized rather than like on other apps where the keyboard floats over top.

I'm thinking this is a result of the fact that unlike Windows 8, Windows Phone 8 doesn’t use WinJS but essentially a C# or VB app with a browser control.

If anyone has experience with this and/or knows how to stop it from happening it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> rather than like on other apps where the keyboard floats over top.

The keyboard moves the PhoneApplicationFrame up for all 3rd party applications. You can't stop this behaviour, but you can adjust for it by listening for page Y transform.

Comment: thanks... that's what I was thinking but searching fond nothing so at least now others looking for the same will hopefully find this.  I'll post my code to handle this later one